# How to use gremlin to get the timestamps which has no data?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

```
g.V('JobDefinition').out("JobDefinitionToJobHistory").has("Timestamp", between("2022-02-01T00:00:00Z", "2022-02-07T00:00:00Z")).group().by("Timestamp").by(count())
```

I have a gremlin query and get the result below. As you can see from the result, there is no data in "2022-02-06T00:00:00Z" and "2022-02-07T00:00:00Z". But I don't know how to get the result ["2022-02-06T00:00:00Z", "2022-02-07T00:00:00Z"] by gremlin query. I want to get the timestamp list which don't have data. Can you give me some suggestions, thanks!

```
[
  {
    "2022-02-01T00:00:00Z": 1,
    "2022-02-02T00:00:00Z": 2,
    "2022-02-03T00:00:00Z": 2,
    "2022-02-04T00:00:00Z": 1,
    "2022-02-05T00:00:00Z": 1,
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gremlin doesn't realize you are asking about a `Date` type. To Gremlin you just have a `String` so I don't think there is much it can do to help in this case. I could maybe think of some tricky things to make it work,(because with Gremlin you can do just about anything) but it will just overcomplicate your code and in the worst case make it perform worse.

In this case, it might just be best to just post process your data in your application and inject the missing values after the query has been executed.

Comment: got it. Thanks, stephen. You have helped me many times. Thanks for your contribution to the community.

Comment: TinkerPop is hoping to have better datetime support for 3.7.0, but that might not help you on CosmosDB which is still roughly supporting much older versions.

Comment: Hi @stephen, sorry to bother you again. Recently I am learning gremlin and I want to know how to solve this question by using gemlin. I know the overcomplicate gremlin which can solve my question can't be used in code, I want to know the answer just for my interest at gremlin. So can you give some more details about how to solve this question by using gremlin, I just want to learn more about gremlin. Thanks!

Comment: sorry - i don't think i want to figure that out even for academic purposes. whatever i came up with would be probably be really arcane and not a great learning tool anyway. some years ago some folks wrote a Gremlin compiler written purely in Gremlin itself! i don't feel the need to dig into how flexible Gremlin can be after seeing that at work :)